# PrimeFaces p:password unmask icon not showing

Tags: primefaces, passwords, icons

PrimeFaces `p:password` unmask icon not showing. Look at html, it uses `ui-password-icon`. But the icon is not defined in jQuery UI themes. What css files need to be included?

```html
<p:password ... toggleMask="true"/>
```

Comment: What theme are you using? Does it work when you use Saga? It's working here https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/password.xhtml

Comment: I use jQuery UI theme: start.  Are jQuery themes still supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery UI themes have been dead since about PrimeFaces 8.0

You are missing all the styles needed for `toggleMask`.  Also for any new component introduced in PF8.0 or higher like ToggleSwitch, Skeleton, Avatar etc etc etc.

You would need to add those new styles yourself to your ThemeRoller theme.  But I recommend getting off of ThemeRoller ASAP.  Its dead and no longer supported

Comment: Tried saga theme, our code are totally broken with the theme. Any migration guide from jquery ui theme to the new primefaces theme? Thanks

Comment: Jquery UI is still alive, right?

Comment: Jquery UI is still supported yes. But PF stopped supporting ThemeRoller probably 4 years ago.  Yes your new theme with Saga will not be a drop in you will need to do some tweaking.  But the end result is those CSS based PrimeTek themes are the future and Jquery ThemeRoller is dead.  The spacing and padding is different in those new themes.

Comment: I don't understand how changing a theme can break code. @eastwater care to share what broke? Maybe we can learn something from it.

Comment: I assumed he doesn't meant "broken" but "doesn't look the same or correct".

Comment: In addition to saga, other themes to choose for community edition? Like a theme zip file in jquery UI?

Comment: You can see the community themes included in PF here: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/primefaces/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources